# using reverse proxy determine which site on webserver to access

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a reverse proxy sitting infront of my web server (My webserver has a few different sites). The reverse proxy is on ssl while the webserver is not. I would like to have it so that when a client sends a request, the reverse proxy will take the ip from this client and then based on this ip redirect it to the proper site on the web browser. I have tried a few things reading apache documentation but I am not sure how to accomplish this any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many different client IPs are we talking?

Comment: Currently it is just 4 different ranges of ip address, but in the future I might need to add more or even just individual ip addresses.